# How do you get a mac address from an IP address on your network?

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking, network-programming

Having issues with a get_mac function i created below, which takes an IP Address and finds its mac address, returning it or None.

The actual python function is:

```
def get_mac(ip_addr):
    "get_mac is used to obtain the mac address of the target ip."
    print "Getting Mac for: %s" % ip_addr
    responses, unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="de:ad:be:ef:ca:fe")/ARP(pdst=ip_addr),timeout=2,retry=10)
    for s,r in responses:
        return r[Ether].src
    return None
```

Im thinking that there may be a better way to do this.   This was taken out of the Black Hat Python book, and im leveraging the imports:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.base_classes import Gen, SetGen
import scapy.plist as plist
from scapy.utils import PcapReader
from scapy.data import MTU, ETH_P_ARP
import os
import sys
import threading
import signal
```

for my entire file file I have been working ith.   I was working on creating a custom tool for a very fine tuned purpose.  I was running it against my buddy to by way of ipconfig told me his IP was 192.168.0.20 so when running against that, i could see the console outputting this information.

```
....
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Received 12 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
....
```

12 times and then printed what i told it to since it returned none.

```
! Failed to find Target Mac
```

Is this the right course of action?  Did my buddy send me the wrong IP address?  I think i saw him give me the ipv4 in `ipconfig`

I guess iam curious if there is a better way then the `srp()` function i ended up calling.

The base sample I was working with was *page 52 of BlackhatPython called:  ARP Cache Poisoning via Scapy.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're just trying to implement an ARP request, then the request should be sent to the MAC broadcast address (`FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF`). You should be filling in your own NIC's MAC address as the source address, both in the Ethernet header, and as the ARP sender-MAC address.

The way ARP typically works is that a broadcast message is sent to the local network, in essence saying "Hey everybody, who has IP address `N.N.N.N`? Tell me `<my MAC address>`." It typically *also* includes the sender's IP address, which in effect says "And oh, by the way, my IP address is `M.M.M.M`."

The response is then usually sent via unicast back to the requester which is why you need to fill in your own MAC as the sender address: so that you get the response.

There are other ARP usages wherein the "who has?" part is a dummy, and the "oh, by the way, my address is..." is the main goal -- that's known as gratuitous ARP since it's often sent without a preceding request and is essentially just announcing the sender's own IP/MAC association.

(It doesn't appear that you meant to ask about ARP cache poisoning, but that's essentially just lying about the "oh, by the way" clause. Either with the wrong MAC address or a completely bogus one.)

The scapy `srp` function is fine for doing this. Probably the easiest way to implement it in python.

Comment: so i guess my answer is that i am *suppose* to use `ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff` as opposed to my standard `de-ad-be-ef-ca-fe`?  but yes, my goal is to successfully do cache poisoning.  It just seems like the srp doesnt seem to return it correctly, which confused me as to why.

Comment: Could there be an issue with the fact that I am not using an ethernet connection?  I am running this as wifi?  I was curious about this, because when i was looking up the docs, it seemed there was a lot of information about ethernet connections.

Comment: There are 4 mac addresses in an ARP: 2 in the Eth header, 2 in the ARP "payload". The dst address in the Eth header determines where the packet goes (and the src identifies where it came from -- probably can lie about that one). The ones in the ARP itself are the ones used for address resolution (and likely what you want to use for poisoning). But the packet won't get to where it needs to go if the Ether dst is not correct. If you set the Ether dst to `de-ad-be-ef-ca-fe`, no machine will even look at it as it won't be addressed to them. It works the same on wifi (at a high level at least).